# How do I download a playlist with youtube-dl starting in the middle?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-dl

I downloaded the video from list using youtube-dl, but due to connectivity problem, I couldn't complete my download all the videos. Only 100 out of 200 videos were completed. After watching few videos, I deleted first 50 videos. Now I want to continue download from 101st video. When I start download from list, it always starts from 1st video. Is there any option available to start download from some specific video other than 1 ?

Extra Info : My list link :  [Android Application Development Tutorial (1 - 200)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A), which is Video Tutorial list.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the command in that way

`youtube-dl --playlist-start=101 <URL>`

this should do the trick

you can also use the -s to simulate the downloading to check you are doing it right

source : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URcb5LJqtMQ

Comment: Any way to specify number where to end or number of videos ?

Comment: --playlist-end NUMBER  // Playlist video to end at (default is last)